# Amazon SQS FIFO Queue send message validation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, fifo

I am working on using amazon's fifo queue and when I send a message I would like to know if the item was added with my call, or if the message was already in the queue and it just returned true

Comment: SQS.SendMessage doesn't return "true" - see the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_SendMessage.html).  Out of curiosity, why does it matter whether it was deduplicated or not? What will you run differently based on this detection?

Comment: I want to add X unique messages to a queue. If one message is already in the queue i would like to try to put another message in a queue until i get to X messages added to the queue from this process

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only have one process adding messages to the queue, just keep track of the `sequenceNumber` from the result (ie: add it to a `Set`) - once you have X unique sequenceNumbers, you're set (no pun intended).

If you have multiple processes adding messages, you'll need to either

1. ensure the messages sent by each process are unique (and thus can use the same mechanism as single process), or
2. use some mechanism of sharing information between processes

   - doing this option properly is likely more expensive than it's worth, and I'd *strongly* suggest either designing for option 1, or revisiting the requirement that each process sends exactly X unique messages, especially if "approximately X" is good enough.